# ASP .NET MVC 5 Html.ValidationMessageFor not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-5

Following is .cshtml code:

```
using (Ajax.BeginForm("UploadEdit", "Widget", new { Type = "SampleSurvey" }, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "SampleSurvey-widget", LoadingElementId = "report-loader", OnBegin = "$('#report-loader').show();", OnSuccess = "$('#report-loader').hide();" }, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", id = "SampleSurvey" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Type)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.IsDealer)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Filter)

    <div class="form form--searchcriteria">
        <fieldset class="">
            <div class="field_group">
                <div class="field">
                    @Html.LabelFor(Model => Model.FirstName, new { @class = "field__label" })
                    <div class="field__controls">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName)
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName)
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="field">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName, new { @class = "field__label" })
                    <div class="field__controls">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastName)
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName)
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="field">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email, new { @class = "field__label" })
                    <div class="field__controls">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email)
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email)
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>         
        <div class="form-control">
            <button id="btnSubmit" class="btn icon icon-location-arrow" type="submit" onclick="$('#report-loader').show();">Send invitation</button>
        </div>

    </div>
}
```

And following is my model:

```
public class SampleSurvey : WidgetBase
{      
    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Maximum 100 characters are allowed in field")]
    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Maximum 100 characters are allowed in field")]
    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress, ErrorMessage = "Invalid field.")]
    [Display(Name = "Email Address")]
    public string Email { get; set; }      

}
```

But still validation is not working upon clicking the submit button, help will highly be appreciated.

Comment: Have you include the jquery.unobtrusive validation file ?

Comment: also check <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/> in web.config

Comment: @MannanBahelim  jquery.unobtrusive is included in BundleConfig.cs and ClientValidationEnabled is also set to true in web.config.

Comment: Firstly, you `[DataType]` attribute has nothing to do with validation (it just renders `type="email"` in the input - you can delete the `ErrorMessage = "..."` since it does nothing) Are you saying you do not get client side validation is you enter no, or more than 100 characters for `FirstName` and `LastName`?

Comment: Note if you want email validation, then use the `[EmailAddress]` attribute.

Comment: Is this a partial view rendered in other main view?

Comment: @StephenMuecke Empty fields are being accepted on submit.  I am now using [EmailAddress] attribute

Comment: @MannanBahelim It is a widget that is rendered in other main view.

Comment: Are you sure that the scripts are being added in the correct order, and no duplicates (`jquery`, `jquery.validate` and `jquery.validate.unobtrusive`)? And are there any other scripts in the view which may be interfering?

Comment: @StephenMuecke Can I add these scripts separately on this view?

Comment: That depends - are they in the layout? (then no - they should only be loaded once)

Comment: U can use a section to add scripts separately on this view. Put this code in your Layout (after the other scripts load)  @RenderSection("scripts", required: false) and then in the view you can do @section scripts
{ <script>Add the script you need </script>}

Comment: Are you using if(!ModelState.IsValid){} to check the validation in the Controller for the given Model?